# Convert hex string to ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, hex, arraybuffer

I have image data in the form of a hex string

```
0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 
0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 
0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, ...
```

So each value is separated by a `,` and `space`

How can I convert this into an `ArrayBuffer` object?

Thanks!

Comment: what steps have you taken to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simpler option is to use teh package hex-to-array-buffer on npm where you can simply use teh function  `hexToArrayBuffer` and convert the hex string to an array buffer.

You can also do it by yourself by doing:

```
var hex = your hex
var typedArray = new Uint8Array(hex.match(/[\da-f]{2}/gi).map(function (h) {
  return parseInt(h, 16)
}))
var buffer = typedArray.buffer
```

Comment: I love the regex soln. Thanks!